# Android client PC server java socket connection fail

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I am a complete beginner in socket network programming. I wants to perform a simple network connection under a same network(using java) and been trying to connect my android phone (client) to my laptop(server) for two days, but has no positive results.

I have tried out many ways like:

1) Include manifest user permission

2) Close FireWall

3) Confirm server ip address by checking ipconfig in cmd

4) Ensure both client and server are on the same network

5) Ensure the right port number and ip address in server (eg: 192.168.x.x)

6) Try out public ip address

And all end up with the saying "Unfortunately, Connection has stopped." While i run my application in my smartphone.

Error:  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Code on Client:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SetGUI();
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}
 public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverName,serverPortNumber);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
public void SetGUI(){
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    readText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_read);
    writeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_write);
}
```

Please help and show any possible solutions. 
Sorry if my English makes you difficult to understand the content.

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your question

Comment: Can you post some of the code you are using?

Comment: Thank you for reading out. Was ignored the exception (newbie to android studio). So sorry and will makes further research on it and update with you all later.@LunarWatcher@NilsSchlüter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error. After applying thread for the codes that handling the connection in my android, everything works beautiful :D